# How show wordpress content image api

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter

i want to show image content in my flutter app . i use wordpress api . 
i use this class to show featuredmedia , title and content

```
 Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : title = json['title']["rendered"],
    excerpt = json['excerpt']["rendered"],
    image = json["_embedded"]['wp:featuredmedia'][0]["media_details"]
        ["sizes"]["medium"]["source_url"],
    date = json['date'],
    content = json['content']["rendered"],
      id = json['id'];
```

and this is wordpress content

"content": {
"rendered": "The PM has warned MPs they are damaging his chances of getting a deal with the EU by trying to block a no-deal Brexit.

\n

Boris Johnson said the UK would leave the bloc “do or die” on 31 October – prompting some MPs to act to stop the UK leaving without an agreement.

\n

But he said the more MPs try to block a no-deal Brexit, “the more likely it is that we’ll end up in that situation”.

\n

It comes after the PM announced he would be suspending Parliament for five weeks over September and October.

\n

Mr Johnson said it was to allow the government to hold a Queen’s Speech and outline its “very exciting agenda” for the future.

\n

But critics claim his intention is to prevent any moves in the Commons to stop a no deal.

\n

https://iraqmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/file-20181002-85614-vu0p6l-300x205.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"205\" srcset=\"https://iraqmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/file-20181002-85614-vu0p6l-300x205.jpg 300w, https://iraqmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/file-20181002-85614-vu0p6l-768x524.jpg 768w, https://iraqmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/file-20181002-85614-vu0p6l.jpg 926w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" />

\n",
"protected": false
},

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Image.network` to display the image once you get the link to that image.

Example Code with solution:

```
    String imageUrl,rawString,i,j;
    [...]
    // At some point of your code
    rawString  = json['content']["rendered"];   
    for(int i=0;i<rawString.length;i++) if(rawString[i]=='=' && rawString[i-1]=='t' && rawString[i-2]=='e' && rawString[i-3]=='s' && rawString[i-4]=='c' && rawString[i-5]=='r' && rawString[i-6]=='s') 
for(j=i+3;(rawString[i]=='.' && (rawString.substring(j,j+4)=="jpg")||rawString.substring(j,j+4)=="png");j++)
   imageUrl = rawString.substring(i,j+4);
    [...]
    // The place where you want to display your widget
    Image.network(
      imageUrl, // Can add more attributes 
    );
```

I have just used logical AND to efficiently find 'srcset=' and then have tried to get the link as a substring by looking for the file extension.

It might not work in all the cases, but something is better than nothing.

> If your facing any other issue similar and if you don't have time to
>   implement your own logic use the `html` package developed by Flutter's
>   official dev team.
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/html
>
> Alternatively you can even refer to either of these 2 packages(since
>   your working with wordpress),
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/wordpress_api

Comment: Thanks but i think there is another easy way

Comment: I have added the link to the package which helped you in the answer so that it becomes suitable to qualify for the right answer.

Comment: i try with this but not work                          Image.network(parse(widget.data.content).body.innerHtml)

Comment: Try using the above solution..The code independent from the html package

Comment: I have attached links to 2 more packages. They'll surely help you in some way as your working with Wordpress.

Comment: Take some time and go through whatever they above packages offer

Comment: Yes, my above soultion with HTML  package  pub.dev/packages/html . and I will try again. thanks